# Words describing being arrogant but in a positive way?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, single-words

Are there any Italian words which describe being arrogant as in wanting to do stuff or achieve something regarded as hard by others, with such word or words having a *positive* connotation?

For instance: ambizioso. Here is what the Devoto Oli has to say about it:

1. Dominato dall'ambizione {so basically as though "possessed" by ambition: I read this as a negative connotation. And then the example:} pochi ambiziosi dichiareranno giustizia e pubblica necessità quello che non è se non capriccio e ambizione loro {so, as though by chance, the example also points out a negative attitude towards the (so-called) "ambiziosi", and then...}
2. Che rivela un eccesso di ottimismo e presunzione (eg. progetto ambizioso).

---

What I am finding is that many, if not most, Italian words involving ambition as part of their dictionary definitions, end up having at least one quasi-neutral and one totally negative hue.

For instance, the saying "andarono come i pifferi di montagna" is an example of this: it is used to depict people who were too sure of their strengths {hence, arrogant}, and were subsequently defeated. This is just one example of how the Italian language always tends to view arrogance in a negative light.

Is it not so?

---

EDIT:

baldanza:

- disinvolta fiducia in sé stesso e nella fortuna: *la naturale baldanza dei giovani*; anche, presunzione, spavalderia.

Comment: Something like "[ambizioso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ambizioso/)"? Although it's indeed not postive, but neither negative and rather neutral, at least as per how I'd interpret it.

Comment: I have amended my question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: «This is just one example of how the Italian language always tends to view arrogance in a negative light.» Jack, this is the second question where you try to make this point. While it is a very interesting conjecture, I don't believe this is the place where it can be settled. Either some researcher in sociolinguistics has already tackled it, or it is difficult to solve it here, by more or less randomly sampling terms and idioms about “arrogance”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not commonly used (it's a bit of an high/formal/obsolete term), I'd say that the best word to use for your meaning would be "baldanzoso" (from the substantive "baldanza"). I can't really associate it with a negative perception of the term.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comment, a more commonly used term is "audace" (from "audacia"). It's also more generic: the "baldanza" is the "audacia" typical of the youth, while the latter is generic.

Comment: Nice one, and some of the synonyms offered by Treccani for [*baldanzoso*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/baldanzoso_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) might qualify too: «animoso, ardimentoso, ardito, audace, baldo, coraggioso, fiero, intrepido, risoluto, sicuro, temerario».

Comment: @DaG, thank you for pointing out these related words. I will look them up and learn  them.

Comment: Anyways, many of these words relate to the concept of risks involved. Sure, it's nice to think it can be done; sometimes, as age may teach us, a slightly different or better approach may help us; blessings to all whom can see clearly into the future! :-)

Comment: Well fair enough.

Comment: And perhaps the opposite of "arrogant" ought to be "undecisive".

Comment: Anyways, I've decided I won't let that discourage me. Huh!

Comment: @JackMaddington another possible opposite would be "humble" (umile), though that's more of an opposite to the "proud" (fiero, orgoglioso) part of audacity. I would say that undecisive is more the opposite of "deciso" or, peraphs in certain contexts, of "risoluto", or even better of the idiom "dalle idee chiare"